# File paths for parsing in Ruby using Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

So I'm writing a test that locates a particular file `metadata.json` to be parsed to Ruby's JSON gem to be tested using RSpec. My directory hierarchy looks like this:

```
|_tests
   - metadata.json
   - Rakefile
   - Gemfile
   |_specs
     -tagging_specs
```

The code was a simple file read passing in the relative path, so:

```
print "Getting values from metadata.json file"
#Path to metadata.json file
metadata = File.read('../metadata.json')
values = JSON.parse(metadata)
```

Which worked fine when invoked directly using the rspec command. But as I plan to right multiple tests I opted to use Rake to manage my specs. Since doing this however I get an error and have to pass in a full directory path such as `home/work/projects/tests/metadata.json`

The error message I get is when using ../metadata.json with Rake is:

```
Failure/Error: metadata = File.read('../metadata.json')

Errno::ENOENT:
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../metadata.json
./spec_tests/tagging_standards_spec.rb:7:in 'read'
./spec_tests/tagging_standards_spec.rb:7:in 'block in <top (required)>'
./spec_tests/tagging_standards_spec.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00072 seconds (files took 0.17953 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

This woukdnt be a problem if it was just me using these tests. However they're meant to provide the base for others to do their work, so their directory paths will of course be different. So is there a way in Ruby or Rake to make this more dynamic and reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__dir_ method returns directory of the current file you're in, so this should work for you:

```
File.read(__dir__ + "/../metadata.json")
```

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to get the "full path" you can use `File::expand_path`

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point. The given pathname may start with a “~”, which expands to the process owner’s home directory (the environment variable HOME must be set correctly). “~user” expands to the named user’s home directory.

For example:

```
File.expand_path('../metadata.json',__FILE__)
```

Here it will first resolve the parent directory of `__FILE__` which the current file from which it is called e.g. `Rakefile` then it will use the relative path passed as `../metadata.json` to find the specific file requested and resolve the absolute path